# SSRS Data rows - can they be 'condensed'?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have the following data layout in an SSRS report

[image: Data Layout]

What I'd like to do is for columns D and E have the entries, per value in Column B, grouped so that they appear as 2 lists with no gaps.

I'm not an SSRS expert hence the question. What I'm looking for is something that looks like this:

[image: New data layout]

I can't change the base data as D and E are linked in the database. From searching it seems that a group and a sort might do it but I can't find a complete answer.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: A few comments. 1.) I assume a typo as the 'c1' in cell E3 in the top table does not appear in the bottom table. 2.) Does your data look like the top table in your database? If not can you post the underlying table structure as I tend to think that this will be easier in SQL and in the "Very difficult" category for doing directly in the report design.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - if it can't easily be done in SSRS then I'll try and solve it in SQL myself - I'll post a solution if I get one or come back for help. Thanks :-)